# Delete files that are not linked from an html file

Tags: bash

Given an html file, something like myfile.html, and a folder with some files in it that are part of the web-page and others that are not linked in the html.

How can you delete the files that are not linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we accept that we'll count as linked anything whose name shows up as a string in the file (which may not strictly be a link, but makes things a bit easier in my head at least):

```
for candidate in folder/*; do
    if ! grep -q "$candidate" myfile.html; then
        rm "$candidate"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. It is extremely unlikely a file will be mentioned, but not linked. This won't leave many useless files standing.

Comment: It could be safer to change `rm "$candidate` to `mv $candidate toErase\$candidate`, assuming the folder `toErase` was created. In that way, no real erasing takes place but the folder gets cleaner. Just a thought.